# Guess the number game, every # is low

Tags: c, function, loops

I've been at this project for hours and hours trying to figure this out but I'm to the point of brain dead where everything I read leaves me confused.

The idea is to enter a number and the program will tell me whether it is right or wrong. Every single time, the end response after I enter a number is that the number is too low.

Also, the final answer states that the answer is too low and that it's correct at the same time.

Finally, this thing is suppose to ask again if the number entered is incorrect, yet I have no knowledge of how to do this.

Literally, the tiniest advice is much appreciated at this point. It's been a long, groaning night.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int number;
//new function
void welcomeMessage(){
    printf("Welcome to my new guessing game!\n");
    printf("Let's get started!\n");
}
//new function
int randomNumber(){

    int range;

    srand(time(NULL));
    range = (20 - 1) + 1;

    number = rand() % range + 1;

    return 0;
}
//new function
int guessInput(){

    int guess, range;

    printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20\n");
    printf("Care to give it a guess? Be careful! You only get 4 tries!\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    return 0;
}
//new function
int wrongAnswer(){

    int guess, number;

        if(guess < number)
        {   
            printf("Try again, your guess is too low\n");
            return 0;
    }

        else if(guess > number)
    {   
            printf("Give it another try, your guess was a bit to high\n");
            return 0;
    }
        return 0;
}
//new function
int correctAnswer(){

    int guess, number;

        if(guess == number)
            printf("Great job! That time you got it right!\n");
            return 0;
}

int main(){
    welcomeMessage();
    randomNumber();
    guessInput();
    wrongAnswer();
    correctAnswer();

}
```

Comment: You're defining new variables in each function -- these aren't 'global' and only exist in those functions.

Comment: Don't call `srand` every time you call `rand`. Call it once at program start.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry, can you explain that further or possibly show me? I don't quite understand.

Comment: "Don't use global variables" ... well he solved _that_ issue ... just perhaps not with the behaviour expected

Comment: Undefined behavior Batman!

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually passing the value of `guess` to `wrongAnswer()` or `correctAnswer()`. `guess` in those two functions is uninitialized and doesn't contain the value stored in `guessInput()`. This is why `wrongAnswer` tells you that the guess is too low and `correctAnswer` tells you that it's correct.

You'll also want to remove the `number` declaration within those functions. You have a global `number` right now that stores the random number, but the new `number` variable declared within your functions will take precedence -- it's uninitialized and doesn't contain the random number like you think it does.

You may want to adjust your `wrongAnswer()` and `correctAnswer()` functions to take `guess` as an integer argument, and remove the `guess` and `number` declarations within those two functions. Something like

```
int wrongAnswer(int guess);
int correctAnswer(int guess);
```

You may also want to consider having your `guessInput()` function return the value of `guess`. Try something like

```
int guessInput()
{   
    int guess;

    printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20\n");
    printf("Care to give it a guess? Be careful! You only get 4 tries!\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    return guess;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    int guess = guessInput();
    wrongAnswer(guess);
    correctAnswer(guess);
    ...
}
```

This way you're passing the value of guess to your two functions so that they can actually evaluate whether the number is correct or incorrect.

You'll also want to look at the value of your return functions. Right now they aren't really telling you anything, and they return 0 regardless. Consider changing them to return 0 if the guess was correct and return 1 if the guess was incorrect.

```
int correctAnswer(int guess)
{   
    if(guess == number) {
        printf("Great job! That time you got it right!\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

With this information you can create a `while` loop to continually ask the user for input until they input the correct answer. Something like

```
int main()
{
    ...
    int is_correct = 1, is_wrong = 1;
    int guess;
    while (is_correct == 1) {
        guess = guess_input();
        is_wrong = wrongAnswer(guess);
        is_correct = correctAnswer(guess);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `while` loop above will call each of the three functions, forever, until the user guesses the correct input. It evaluates `is_correct == 1`, constantly checking the value of `is_correct`, and repeating itself. When `is_correct == 0` the loop will break and your program will terminate. This is where the return values I mentioned above come in -- a return value of 0 indicates a correct answer and will allow your program to stop. A return value of 1 will repeat the loop. There are other ways to do this, but it may help while you're starting out.

Hopefully this helps you out. I'd also consider redesigning your `wrongAnswer()` and `correctAnswer()` functions -- do you really need two? Could you reduce that to one function?

Comment: Thanks for all of this. Sadly it requires me to have two functions for wrong and right answers. Preferably I'd like to simplify it down into one but that isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The Most basic issue that i see with the program is that you are not passing values to the functions. Each function is just working in itself and the value or should i say the 'number' it has to work with is not being passed into them.

You can use global variables or pass the values directly. This is what i would do:

The input function:

```
int guessInput(){
int guess, range;
printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20\n");
printf("Care to give it a guess? Be careful! You only get 4 tries!\n");
scanf("%d", &guess);
return guess;}
```

The Random Number Generator Function:

```
int randomNumber(){
int range;
srand(time(NULL));
range = (20 - 1) + 1;
number = rand() % range + 1;
return number;}
```

The Answer Function: ( you really don't need 2 functions for this )

```
int Answer(int guess, int number){

int counter=0;
    if(guess < number)
    {   
        printf("Try again, your guess is too low\n");
        counter=1;
}

    else if(guess > number)
{   
        printf("Give it another try, your guess was a bit to high\n");
        counter=1;
}

    else if(guess == number)
{   
        printf("Great job! That time you got it right!\n");
        counter=2;
}
    return counter;}
```

Now that all your functions can accept variables, Modify the Main function

```
int main(){

int number=0;
int guess=0;
int answr=0; // This does not have to exist but since your doing a return.
welcomeMessage();
number=randomNumber();
guess=guessInput();
Do {
answr=Answer(guess,number);
}(while answr<2)
}
```

So when the counter reaches 2, which means that the answer is right, the while loop will stop when the correct answer is guessed by the user.

PS: You may need to polish my code a bit since im also in a brain dead mode atm. :D

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I agree that it would be more simple to keep the answer functions down to one, but the instructions say we must split them into two, one for correct, one for incorrect.

Comment: Ok, If that is a requirement, you can go with the initial idea and have both the functions in the while loop ( modified the way i created preferrably ). Making sure you have return values for the result, the code will execute both the functions and once the return value for the correct answer is met, you can make the loop exit.

Let me know if you would like me to create a code snippet for you.